# Finding equation of plane containing line of intersection

Tags: calculus, geometry, vectors

**Problem:** Find the equation of the plane containing the line of intersection of the planes $x+y+z=0$ and $2x + y - 3z = 2$, and perpendicular to the plane $x - 2y - 5z = 17$.

**Attempt at a solution:** The direction vector of the line of intersection is given by the crossproduct of the two normals of the planes. The two normals are $(1,1,1)$ and $(2,1,-3)$. The crossproduct of these is \begin{align*} \begin{vmatrix} \hat{i} & \hat{j} & \hat{k} \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 & - 3 \end{vmatrix} \end{align*} which gives $\hat{i}(-3-1) + \hat{j} (-3 - 2) + \hat{k}(1-2)$. Hence the direction vector of the line of intersection is \begin{align*} \mathbf{r} = -4 \hat{i} - 5 \hat{j} - \hat{k} \end{align*} Since our plane must also be perpendicular to the plane $x - 2y - 5z = 17$, it will be parallel to the normal of that plane, which is \begin{align*} \mathbf{n} = \hat{i} - 2 \hat{j} - 5 \hat{k} \end{align*} I'm not sure where to go from here, any help?

**Edit:** The direction vector is $\mathbf{r} = -4 \hat{i} + 5 \hat{j} - \hat{k}$. A point on the line of intersection (setting $x = 0$) is $(0,1/2,-1/2)$. A normal to our plane can be found by taking the crossproduct of $\mathbf{n}$ and our directionvector $\mathbf{r}$. The normal is \begin{align*} \mathbf{a} = 27 \hat{i} + 21 \hat{j} - 3 \hat{k}. \end{align*} Hence the equation of the plane is \begin{align*} 27(x - 0) + 21 (y-1/2) + 3 (z + 1/2) = 0.\end{align*}

Comment: Your computation of the crossproduct is wrong. The normal to the first plane is $(1,1,1)$, but $(1,1,1) \cdot (-4, -5, -1) \ne 0$.

Comment: I don't see how it's wrong. I edited my post to show how I arrived at my solution. Can you tell me what I did wrong then?

Comment: The second term  in the cross product has wrong sign. It must be $-j(-3-2)$.

Comment: Ok thanks, that was a stupid mistake. Can you check my answer now, at the bottom of my post? Also, does it matter in which order I take the crossproduct to arrive at a normal of a plane?

Comment: No...taking the crossproduct in the other order will negate the answer, and if $k$ is normal to a plane, so is $-k$. In fact, if you follow through the whole process, the plane equations you'll get with the two approaches will be negatives of each other... which is fine: they'll have identical solutions.

Comment: It's OK, but maybe another wrong sign in the third term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you know that the plane contains the vector $r$ and the vector $n$, you can determine its normal vector $k$. It also must contain the intersection line, hence contain at least one point of that line. So you need to find a single point $P$ of that line. I suggest you do so by setting $x = 0$ and solving for $y$ and $z$. Once you've done that, the plane equation is

$$
(X - P) \cdot k = 0.
$$

But as I noted in my comment, you've computed $r$ incorrectly, so you need to fix that.